# Angular deploy-url assets path

Tags: angular, iis, url-rewriting

As you all might know there is a problem with asset path when deploying Angular to a path other than root: any '/assets' path that exists in your templates or style sheets doesn't get prefixed with the deployment path.

I want to write an IIS rewrite rule that checks if a `/assets/...` path exists inside my deployment path and if so, rewrites the url accordingly. For example, lets say I have an asset at `/assets/1.jpg` and my deployment url is `/ui/` I want a rewrite rule that takes the request URI, prefixes it with `/ui` checks if it is an actual file system file and if so, rewrites the request uri to `/ui/assets/1.jpg`.

I tried the following but I know this doesn't work:

```html
<rule name="angular asset" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="/ui/{REQUEST_URI}" matchType="IsFile" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/ui/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

What is the correct way to write such a rule?

**Clarification** I want the rewrite rule to work for any prefix path not just `/assets`

Comment: Does setting the `APP_BASE_HREF` not work?

Comment: Nop, that's not a solution, I want the app to be based at the root '/'.

Answer (score -2):

Build angular app with deploy-url option like this:

```
ng b --deploy-url /ui/
```

Next publish your application and host under IIS

Try updating rewrite rule as follows

```
<rule name="angular asset" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="(.*)"/>
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/ui/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

Comment: Are you hosting the angular app inside an MVC app? Also, when you load the angular app in browser does the `main.bundle.js` file loads successfully?

Comment: Yes everything works perfectly, the only problem is `/assets/...` paths. I want to mention also that I am an Angular veteran, so angular is not the problem here. IIS rewrite rules are.

Comment: @AviadP. Try the updated url-rewrite rule in the answer

Comment: That can work but it is limited to `/assets` paths I want it to work for any path... I am going to clarify my question

Comment: That cannot work since `{REQUEST_URI}` is never a file because it is in the form of `/assets/...` and a file is only in the form of a full file system path name, if anything `{REQUEST_FILENAME}` is the thing we're after, but then we can't inject a base path in the middle of it. Or at least that's what I am asking for in my question.